# Do Catholics have to accept the early chapters of Genesis as literal historical truth?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, genesis

Do Catholics have to accept the early chapters of Genesis as literal historical truth? or can they read them as historical mythology? (Mythology which is based on history, with characters who were real people, some events actually happened etc.)

Comment: The answer these days is a clear no. We've had quite [a few questions along similar lines](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=genesis+catholic) already - perhaps you can refine yours further to something that shows a little more research and is not a duplicate or near duplicate.

Comment: @bruisedreed The [1909 Pontifical Biblical Commission](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/32770/1787) condemned that the "three chapters of Genesis contain not accounts of actual events, accounts, that is, which correspond to objective reality and historical truth".

Comment: @Geremia If that were dogma, then Catholics would necessarily be Young Earth Creationists. That's not what you're saying is it?

Comment: @bruisedreed YECs think _yom_ can only mean a 24 hour day. There is no unanimous consent among the Fathers that it must, and the [1909 PBC](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/scripture/oldtestament/commission.htm) said this: "VIII : In the designation and distinction of the six days mentioned in the first chapter of Genesis may the word _Yom_ (day) be taken either in the literal sense for the natural day or in an applied sense for a certain space of time, and may this question be the subject of free discussion among exegetes?
Answer: In the affirmative. "

Comment: @Geremia so that was a more critical part to quote as it contains the word literal as per the OP & confirms my first comment.

Comment: @bruisedreed I don't understand what you're saying. _Yom_ in Hebrew can _literally_ mean a 24 hour period of time _or_ it can _literally_ mean an indefinite duration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52215/discussion-between-bruised-reed-and-geremia).